# Training a segmentation model with pre-created batches of image data in Keras 3

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a usecase where I need to manually make my batches of data prior to feeding it to the model for training.

Let's say I have **(256 x 100 x 100)** images, and my manually created batches' dimensions are **(32 x 100 x 100)**. If my trainset is arranged in order such that `[batch_1, batch_2, ... batch_8]` resulting the original shape (256 x 100 x 100).

when I feed this to the `model.fit()`, give the batch size as **32**, and give `shuffle=False`, would the model properly get each of my manual batches for training sequentially, without mixing up data points from each batch and creating new batches of size **32**?

I am using `Keras 3.0.1`.